# How to upgrade "2nd" installation of Python on Linux/Centos

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looking to upgrade a "secondary" version of Python on my Centos System from 2.7.9 to 2.7.14.  Note: my version of python that the OS uses is 2.6 and I'm not looking to upgrade that.

I've seen many posts about installing an additional version of python on Linux but none on how to upgrade that "additional" version.

Comment: how did you install 2.7.9 to begin with ? are the two bin directories side by side? are you using virtual environments? More detail would lead to better advice.

Comment: +1 to comment above, It depends a lot on how you installed the secondary version of python. So, please provide that.

Comment: The executables for the second version (2.7.9) are installed in /usr/local/bin. I believe 2.7.9 was originally installed by downloading the tar file and then using make with "altinstall" but honestly not positive.  2.7.9 was installed a while ago... Thx.

Comment: maybe try removing the 2.7.9 installation and install 2.7.14 using the same procedure you may have used installing 2.7.9.

Comment: I guess that is a possibility.  Do you know the recommended method to uninstall the 2.7.9 version?